# Sscanf in C - reading numbers from a .txt. file

Tags: c, scanf

I have written a program, which is reading all the numbers from a `.txt` file - it is working fine. However, I would like to use only one `sscanf` function in my program reading all the numbers instead of using `isdigit(*poi)` and `sscanf` again.

If I don't use `isdigit(*poi)`, I will not get the numbers, which would be at the beginning of a line in the `.txt` file.

How can I tell `sscanf` to keep reading even if there is no string to match?

Code:

```
int test(FILE *file, FILE *file2){
    int l = 0;
    int nc = 0;
    char buffer[1000];
    char *poi = NULL;
    fprintf(file2, "\n");
    while(fgets(buffer, 1000, file) != NULL){
        poi = buffer;
        while(*poi){
            if(isdigit(*poi)){
                sscanf(poi, "%d%n",&zahl[l].number, &nc);
                poi += nc;
                fprintf(file2, "%d ", zahl[l].number);
            }
            if(1 == sscanf(poi, "%*[^0-9]%d%n",&zahl[l].number, &nc)){
                poi += nc;
                fprintf(file2, "%d ", zahl[l].number);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
            l++;

        }
        fprintf(file2, "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample text in `.txt`:

```
text 2025 text text 25 text text text 1h text
26 text text text text 4,5h.
text text text text 19h
```

Output should be:

```
2025 25 1
26 4 5 
19
```

Appending of would be fine:

```
    if(1 == sscanf(poi, "%*[^0-9]%d%n",&zahl[l].number, &nc)){
            poi += nc;
            fprintf(file2, "%d ", zahl[l].number);
        }
```

Instead of using :

```
        if(isdigit(*poi)){
            sscanf(poi, "%d%n",&zahl[l].number, &nc);
            poi += nc;
            fprintf(file2, "%d ", zahl[l].number);
        }
```

Comment: you can do it with `scanf`, but it gets tricky and error prone. See, for example, this article: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html. In favour of writing understandable code, I'd use `scanf` to parse only when you are sure what you are parsing, e.g. a number, and even in such cases, I'd prefer strtol or similar functions.

Comment: Thats true :) But it is enough for me as I am a C Beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to use only one sscanf function in my program

Use the return value of `sscanf()`.  When it is not 1, increment `poi` and re-scan at the next character.

```
while(fgets(buffer, 1000, file) != NULL){
  poi = buffer;
  while(*poi){
    int nc = 0; 
    int cnt = sscanf(poi, "%d%n", &zahl[l].number, &nc);
    if (cnt == 1) {
      poi += nc;
      fprintf(file2, "%d ", zahl[l].number);
    } else {
      poi++;
    }
  }
  fprintf(file2, "\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution is working as it should be. I only changed the else statement of my code to poi++ and I get all the numbers of the .txt file.

Comment: @keita063 With only [that change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809443/sscanf-in-c-reading-numbers-from-a-txt-file/59810351?noredirect=1#comment105764073_59810351) , code will mis-read "123-456".  It comes down to how general purpose we make code.  This solution has trouble with values outside `int` range.  We could use `long long`, but that too has limited range.

Answer (score 2):

make `%[^0-9]%n` a separate `sscanf`. Set `nc` to zero and if this `sscanf` fails, zero will be added to `offset`.
`sscanf` for a integer and if that fails, break out of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char *poi = NULL;
    char *lines[] = {
    "text 2025 text text 25 text text text 1h text"
    , "26 text text text text 4,5h."
    , "text text text text 19h"};
    int value = 0;
    int nc = 0;
    for ( int each = 0; each < 3; ++each) {
        poi = lines[each];
        while ( 1) {
            nc = 0;
            sscanf ( poi, "%*[^0-9]%n", &nc);
            poi += nc;
            if ( 1 == sscanf ( poi, "%d%n", &value, &nc)) {
                printf ( "%d ", value);
                poi += nc;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to handle - numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char *poi = NULL;
    char *lines[] = {
    "text 2025 text text 25 text text text 1h text"
    , "26 text text text text 4,-5h."
    , "text text text text 19h"};
    int value = 0;
    int nc = 0;
    for ( int each = 0; each < 3; ++each) {
        poi = lines[each];
        while ( 1) {
            nc = 0;
            sscanf ( poi, "%*[^0-9]%n", &nc);
            poi += nc;
            if ( poi > lines[each]) {
                if ( '-' == *(poi - 1)) {
                    --poi;
                }
            }
            if ( 1 == sscanf ( poi, "%d%n", &value, &nc)) {
                printf ( "%d ", value);
                poi += nc;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This  approach fails when numbers begins with a sign.